# Fit all images with gap in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My thumbnail images are currently sized to 240 by 125 so it is not properly sized for all of them to fit horizontally in a div.

How can I get them to display horizontally in a grid? Also, how do I get the resized images to have the same aspect ratio and a gap of 15px in between them?

My CSS

```css
#full { height:400px; background:#FAFAFA;}
#thumbs { height:150px; background:#E7E7E7; }
#thumbs img { float:left; margin:0 15px; }
```

Here is my jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#thumbs > img').width($('#thumbs').width()/$('#thumbs > img').length-15);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you want a 15px gap in between `img`s but you set `margin:0 15px`, which means both left and right are 15px so the gap in between is 30px, that is the problem. You should set only one side `margin-left:15px`.

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $img = $('#thumbs > img'),
        len = $img.length,
        gap = $img.css('margin-left').replace('px',''),//15
        divW = $('#thumbs').width()-gap;

    $img.width(divW/len-gap);
});
```

Comment: I changed it but not working. One img still not fit.

Comment: Okay, there are missing pieces in your computation. I've updated the answer.